# Why does a lambda expression need a explicity return in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning Room with the sample code RoomWordsSample at https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin.

The Code A is from [WordRoomDatabase.kt](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.kt)

1:  I can't understand why the author need to add the code `INSTANCE = instance`, so I remove it and Code B works well, can you tell me why?

2:  In my mind, the latest expression in a lambda expression will return result, the `val instance = Room.databaseBuilder( ...` is latest expression in Code C, but Code C cann't pass compile, why?

**Code A**

```
@Database(entities = [Word::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
                context: Context,
                scope: CoroutineScope
        ): WordRoomDatabase {           
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                        "word_database"
                )
                        .addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback(scope))
                        .build()

                INSTANCE = instance                
                instance
            }
        }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Database(entities = [Word::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
                context: Context,
                scope: CoroutineScope
        ): WordRoomDatabase {           
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                        "word_database"
                )
                        .addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback(scope))
                        .build()                        
                instance
            }
        }
}
```

**Code C**

```
@Database(entities = [Word::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
                context: Context,
                scope: CoroutineScope
        ): WordRoomDatabase {           
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                        "word_database"
                )
                        .addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback(scope))
                        .build()                       

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: INSTANCE is a Singleton so it needs to be set the first time you instanciate it, that's why the author sets it `INSTANCE = instance`. The next time you call it, you will get the same instance instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code A is implementation of [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. It's aim to have only 1 instance of a class. 
So, Code A checks if `INSTANCE` is null (was class instance created or not), and if not, it creates instance of WordRoomDatabase class and assigns it to `INSTANCE` variable. Subsequent calls to `getDatabase` will return `INSTANCE`, and not create new `WordRoomDatabase` each time.

Code B breaks this pattern, not saving `instance` to static `INSTANCE` variable. Code will work, but for each subsequent call to `getDatabase` new instance of `WordRoomDatabase` will be created.

Code C not working, because `getDatabase` method must return  `WordRoomDatabase` instance, but it returns nothing (assignments are not expressions in Kotlin)